# Car exhaust smoking (white smoke) a lot when driving

Tags: oil, bmw, exhaust, sludge

I have a bmw e60 with low mileage, I had an overdue service that I got done at garage, they advised that I have sludge/soot in the oil judging by inspection of oil filter.as I drove it home alot of smoke emitted from the exhaust ? Leaving a trail of white smoke, I let car cool down for a few hours then checked for creamy oil on dipstick and engine oil cap, but that was normal, I then checked radiator water and that was a little low so I filled up, I checked for any oil leaks underneath the car and on engine and found nothing ? The following day I started car up in the morning and no smoke, I let the car warm up and still no smoke, so I drove around the block and smoke started coming out of exhaust excessively? Not sure what problem is ? Although there are no unusual sounds from engine and no power loss ?

Comment: Normally a cracked or warped head would cause this but not sure how the garage didn’t spot this. Are you sure it’s white smoke and not just condensation from the exhaust?

Comment: Does the exhaust smell like coolant?  That can indicate a cooling system leak into the combustion chamber.  Sounds like a head gasket problem though, possibly caused by a failed gasket or a warped head (or both).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the car an automatic? If somehow (yah, big "if" eh) the engine is sucking in automatic tranny fluid, it would smoke white.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies  A garage had a look at it today and noticed clean oil from the service coming from the exhaust, also noticed oil leakage from the turbo and stated turbo needs replacing. He stated that when car is started from cold it does not smoke, as engine warms up and oil becomes thinner due to warming up the smoke begins to come out, he priced it up stating the turbo will cost £280 for reconditioning & £180 labour is this reasonable